# Laravel livewire element after leave a text field gives error 419

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

When i move out of field it gives error This page has expired due to inactivity. Would you like to refresh the page.

livewire version - 2.3.18

```
class User extends Component
{

    public $name;
```

In view

```
<input wire:model.lazy="name" name="name" class="appearance-none border-0 rounded-xl w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight bg-concrete-500 focus:outline-none placeholder-tundora-500 placeholder-opacity-50 font-poppins font-regular focus:shadow-md focus:border-0 focus:ring-0 md:px-8" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

include this in your `VerifyCsrfToken`

```php
protected $except = [
        'livewire/*',
    ];
```

Comment: I'm making a Laravel package that I'm using livewire, but I can not use this method! Is there another solution?

Comment: use custom middlewareGroup without VerifyCsrfToken for your route.